# prettier, тонкости в конфигурации

Tags: reactjs, prettier

Как в prettier настроить три вещи:

1. `{name: 1}` а prettier делает `{name: 1,}`, как от этого избавиться?
2. как сделать что бы было `{a}` а не `{ a }`?
3. что бы в конце объектов не было точки с запятой. У нас есть `const a = {name: 1}`, а он делает  `const a = {name: 1};`, но что бы в конце остальных строк точки с запятой были.
4. И что бы в React, форматировал все кроме jsx.

Comment: Посмотрите статью https://maxpfrontend.ru/vebinary/nastroyka-eslint-prettier-pre-commit-hook-create-react-app-visual-studio-code/